# Find out what symbol enumerate is using

Tags: beamer, symbols, enumerate

I'm working on a poster in `beamer`.  The style uses

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]
```

which generates a number inside a circle as the symbol for items in `enumerate`.  I'd like to reference an item in my enumerated lists later on the poster (in the middle of a sentence), but I can't figure out how to generate the same symbol that enumerate is using.  How can I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using a `\Myref` command (the original definition for the `circle` template can be found in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]

\newcommand\Myref[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
  \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{0ex}{1ex}{2ex}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{.75ex}}{1.2ex}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
    \pgftext[base]{\color{fg}\ref{#1}}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

A cross-reference to item~\Myref{test}.
\begin{enumerate}
\item A test item
\item Another test item\label{test}
\item Yet another test item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]